# Google Drive desktop using high amount of RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, google-drive-for-desktop

I tried to backup my daily work with Google Drive Desktop, syncing an entire SSD drive. However, since this process started, the PC became slow and when I look at the process manager, the RAM monitor shows 98% usage mainly from Google Drive Desktop.

I understand that I am syncing 52GB of data but I would think that Google Drive should have a limit on the amount of RAM it uses for this sync. How can I stop Google Drive from consuming so much RAM?

**PC specifications**
OS: **windows 10 Pro**
Processor: **Intel Core i7**
RAM: **32 GB**

Comment: This is a non-issue. Any process will use as much memory the OS can afford and the OS should manage it efficiently and it does. If that amount wasn't available it wouldn't be assigned, end of story. And if memory is available and a process can use it then it should. The problem here is just *perception*, I don't think that such usage created any real issue with other processes. If it did you didn't mention it.

Comment: Well, the sentence "the PC became slow" means unusable due the high use of RAM, that's not a perception. I apologize if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - that's true, except what you are not acknowledging is the user may wish to undertake other computational tasks on the machine.  That becomes very difficult if a "resource hogging app" eats all the ram.  For example, on windows, a classic issue when Google Drive is using 95% RAM, is the saving of documents - or virtually any windows explorer task.  These folder / explorer tasks becomes impossible and take several minutes to execute, while Drive is prioritising jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a complete solution, but I did find a workaround that maybe could help you.

**Workaround**
Instead of syncing a bunch of projects (the entire drive), I decided to move all the data to another drive and started syncing folder by folder. Once all the files in each folder are synced, I move another folder and so on. This allowed me to achieve all the backup successfully.

Also, I experienced an improvement in sync performance when I disabled antivirus for a while.

Yes, it took me a lot of work. Yes, the software should improve. Yes, there are other services with a better sync manager. But some of us stick to Drive because of using Google One.

**Observation 1**
Maybe one day we can mark some folders to ignore, especially the node_modules folder which takes a long time to sync.

**Observation 2**
This workaround helps me to achieve the first backup of my entire device. After that point GDD works like a charm.

Comment: This is a very poor workaround - not your fault though, Google Drive does not give any possibility to allow users to have any control over which folders to ignore etc.  That used to be an option in the older version, but now it's all or nothing, so doing what you've suggested is the only way to achieve a managed backup over time.... How frustrating.